# Do all the special stickers in Paper Mario have a use in-game?

Tags: paper-mario-sticker-star

In Paper Mario: Sticker Star on 3DS, any time you find an object (scissors, baseball bat, radiator, etc) you can turn it into a special sticker. They are usually quite effective in battles, but several of them are required to progress through the game (e.g. the refrigerator cools down the volcano level).

However, I have found many objects and made stickers of them, but haven't found a use for them yet. I am very near the end of the game now so I was wondering, does every special sticker have a use somewhere in the game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have completed the game now so can answer this. In short, **no**. You only need a couple of Thing stickers to solve puzzles and defeat enemies.

However, some of the times when you need a Thing sticker you can use one of many. For example when freezing the lava in Rugged Road, both the Refrigerator and Air Conditioner stickers work.